# Программное создание 2d объектов в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, объекты, 2d, рисование

Я решил изучать юнити. Сейчас я делаю клон Ball Blast, и у меня возникла следующая проблема.

Задача в том, чтобы переодично в рандомном (по x) месте появлялись окружности рандомного цвета, радиуса и с рандомным числом посередине. У них должен быть `circle collider` и `rigidbody 2d`. Получается я должен создавать эти шары из скрипта. Так вот, я не знаю как это сделать.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаёте *prefab* нужного вам объекта(на сцене создаёте нужный объект и перетаскиваете его в окно просмотра файлов). Далее в коде с помощью метода *Instantiate* создаёте новый экземпляр объекта и затем уже задаёте ему нужные параметры(цвет, радиус, число) с помощью *getComponent<>()*.

В документации Unity есть статья про это: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Comment: Я говорил о том чтобы прям нарисовать окружность, но этот вариант тоже хорош. У меня остался один вопрос. Я добавляю цифру на шар с помощью 3D Text. Наверняка это неправильно, потому что сама игра в 2d. Есть ли способ сделать лучше?

Comment: @МихаилМуратов Используйте 2d текст. Он доступен, как элемент canvas. Если у вас в игре уже есть canvas, сто просто добавьте текстовый объект, а если нет, то почитайте про canvas и круги тогда тоже, возможно создавайте в нём.

Comment: А что в плане производительности? Лучше добавлять круги как объекты или как элементы canvas?

Comment: 1) На самом деле, если у вас меньше 500 кругов можете не заботиться о производительности. 2) Элемент canvas - объект. Я так понимаю, что вы имеете в виду спрайты. Можно делать и через спрайты в 3d пространстве, и через объекты на canvas. Я бы делал через canvas.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, попробую